# c++ making an array null using foreach

Tags: c++, arrays, foreach, null

```
Node* nodes[3];

for (Node* eachNode:nodes) {
    eachNode = 0; //if i try to dereference it gives seg fault
}                 // eg. *eachNode = 0;

if (nodes[0] == 0) {
    cout << "Null";
} else
    cout << "Not null";

cout << '\n';

Node* nodes2[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { //this way works fine
    nodes2[i] = 0;
}

if (nodes2[0] == 0) {
    cout << "Null";
} else
    cout << "Not null";
```

Hi guys I am trying to make all my objects in an array equal to null. When using a for loop it works fine but when I use a foreach loop it breaks.

The output i get is

Not null

Null

I think i have to dereference the nodes in the foreach loop but it gives a seg fault.

Does anyone know whats wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe instead you should try:

```
for(Node *&eachNode : nodes) {
    eachNode = nullptr;
}
```

This way you get a reference as opposed to the value, and you can appropriately set it to `nullptr`.

I'm not super experienced in C++ 11, but I did have a read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for more information about this new range construct.

Comment: You were right. I still used 0 instead if nullptr because I wanted to learn why it was wrong but i changed

for(Node* eachNode : nodes) {
    eachNode = 0;
}

to

for(Node* &eachNode : nodes) {
    eachNode = 0;
}

and now theyre both null. thanks

Comment: @james1194430 Make sure to accept an answer if you feel it's adequate. :)

Comment: More idiomatic would be `for (auto& node : nodes) node = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

The loop you wrote loops over the *values* of the array:

```
for (Node* eachNode:nodes) {
    eachNode = 0;
}
```

The above loop could as well have been written using `auto`:

```
for (auto eachNode:nodes) {
    eachNode = 0;
}
```

The problem with the above loops is that `eachNode` is *not* the pointer stored in the array, but a copy of that pointer stored in a local variable of the loop.

If you wish to set the node to null, *you need a reference to the memory location where you want to set it*. You get that reference by referring to the array element using `auto&`:

```
for (auto& eachNode:nodes) {
    eachNode = 0;
}
```

This last segment will likely do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are passed by value. So setting the `eachNode = 0;` will change the value, otherwise you are trying to dereference sonething that isn’t a pointer.